# why html font-size calculate the wrong font-size

Tags: html, css

I set the html root font-size with 50%, the chrome default font-size is 16px, so actually I think the font-size should be 8px. But when I check the real font-size withe chrome dev tool, it said 9px. I wonder the reason. By the way the chrome version is 107.0.5304.121.

```
html {
  font-size: 50%;
}
```

[image]

I think maybe it is because of my chrome default setting. I set chrome font min-size 0. maybe you set the min font size 12px.

[image]

Comment: Looks fine on the version 107.0.5304.122. https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGFIA.gif

Comment: I've the same version as yours 107.0.5304.121, on mac. style body font-size 50%, gives font-size 8px. So seems ok

Comment: OMG, it is so wired.

Comment: hi guys, can you help to conform the chrome min font size settings?